# ProGuard: "java.exe" exited with code 1 after adding ModernHTTPClient

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, proguard, visual-studio-2017, android-proguard

In the `Xamarin.Forms` project I added `ModernHTTPClient` library and now the ProGuard step breaks with error:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2025,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.`

(Previously, I had some issues with ProGuard but was able to get it to work while targeting Android 7.1 by upgrading ProGuard to latest version.)

Some of the details from the log file are below.

```
2>  Proguard (TaskId:363)
2>    AndroidSdkDirectory: C:\android-sdk\ (TaskId:363)
2>    JavaPlatformJarPath: C:\android-sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar (TaskId:363)
2>    ClassesOutputDirectory: obj\Release\android\bin\classes (TaskId:363)
2>    AcwMapFile: obj\Release\acw-map.txt (TaskId:363)
2>    ProguardGeneratedApplicationConfiguration: obj\Release\proguard\proguard_project_primary.cfg (TaskId:363)
2>    ProguardJarInput: obj\Release\proguard\__proguard_input__.jar (TaskId:363)
2>    ProguardJarOutput: obj\Release\proguard\__proguard_output__.jar (TaskId:363)
2>    ProguardGeneratedReferenceConfiguration: (TaskId:363)
2>      obj\Release\proguard\proguard_project_references.cfg (TaskId:363)
2>    ProguardGeneratedApplicationConfiguration: (TaskId:363)
2>      obj\Release\proguard\proguard_project_primary.cfg (TaskId:363)
2>    ProguardCommonXamarinConfiguration: (TaskId:363)
2>      obj\Release\proguard\proguard_xamarin.cfg (TaskId:363)
2>    ProguardConfigurationFiles: (TaskId:363)
2>      
2>          {sdk.dir}tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt;
2>          {intermediate.common.xamarin};
2>          {intermediate.references};
2>          {intermediate.application};
2>          ;
2>       (TaskId:363)
2>    ExternalJavaLibraries: (TaskId:363)
2>    DoNotPackageJavaLibraries: (TaskId:363)
2>    UseProguard: False (TaskId:363)
2>    EnableLogging: False (TaskId:363)
2>    DumpOutput: obj\Release\proguard\dump.txt (TaskId:363)
2>    PrintSeedsOutput: obj\Release\proguard\seeds.txt (TaskId:363)
2>    PrintMappingOutput: obj\Release\proguard\mapping.txt (TaskId:363)
2>  Environment Variables passed to tool: (TaskId:363)
2>    JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 (TaskId:363)
2>  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\\bin\java.exe -jar C:\android-sdk\tools\proguard\lib\proguard.jar -include C:\android-sdk\\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt -include obj\Release\proguard\proguard_xamarin.cfg -include obj\Release\proguard\proguard_project_references.cfg -include obj\Release\proguard\proguard_project_primary.cfg "-injars 'obj\Release\proguard\__proguard_input__.jar';'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v7.1\mono.android.jar';'obj\Release\__library_projects__\FormsViewGroup\library_project_imports\formsviewgroup.jar';'obj\Release\__library_projects__\OkHttp\library_project_imports\okhttp-2.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar';'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\embedded\libs\internal_impl-23.3.0.jar';'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\embedded\libs\internal_impl-23.3.0.jar';'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar'" "-libraryjars 'C:\android-sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar'" -outjars "obj\Release\proguard\__proguard_output__.jar" -optimizations !code/allocation/variable  (TaskId:363)
2>  ProGuard, version 5.3.3 (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$Callback$DismissEvent' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$Callback' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$Duration' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$DefaultBehavior' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuHeaderItem' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuItem' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuTextItem' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$ViewHolder' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams$ScrollFlags' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$OnOffsetChangedListener' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'mono.android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout_OnOffsetChangedListenerImplementor' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior$State' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$OnVisibilityChangedListener' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.design.widget.HeaderBehavior' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'mono.android.support.design.widget.NavigationView_OnNavigationItemSelectedListenerImplementor' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'android.support.design.widget.SwipeDismissBehavior$OnDismissListener' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'mono.android.support.design.widget.SwipeDismissBehavior_OnDismissListenerImplementor' (TaskId:363)
...
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'com.squareup.okhttp.Authenticator' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'com.squareup.okhttp.Callback' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'com.squareup.okhttp.Interceptor$Chain' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'com.squareup.okhttp.Interceptor' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'okio.ForwardingSink' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration doesn't specify which class members to keep for class 'okio.ForwardingSource' (TaskId:363)
...
2>  Reading program jar [C:\Users\user\Desktop\MyProjectXXX\MyProjectXXX.Mobile\MyProjectXXX.Mobile.Android\obj\Release\__library_projects__\FormsViewGroup\library_project_imports\formsviewgroup.jar] (TaskId:363)
2>  Reading program jar [C:\Users\user\Desktop\MyProjectXXX\MyProjectXXX.Mobile\MyProjectXXX.Mobile.Android\obj\Release\__library_projects__\OkHttp\library_project_imports\okhttp-2.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar] (TaskId:363)
2>  Reading program jar [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar] (TaskId:363)
2>  Reading program jar [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar] (TaskId:363)
2>  Reading program jar [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar] (TaskId:363)
2>  Reading program jar [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\embedded\libs\internal_impl-23.3.0.jar] (TaskId:363)
2>  Reading program jar [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar] (TaskId:363)
2>  Reading program jar [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar] (TaskId:363)
2>  Reading program jar [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar] (TaskId:363)
2>  Reading program jar [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\embedded\libs\internal_impl-23.3.0.jar] (TaskId:363)
2>  Reading program jar [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar] (TaskId:363)
2>  Reading program jar [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar] (TaskId:363)
2>  Reading library jar [C:\android-sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar] (TaskId:363)
2>  Initializing... (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'android.support.annotation.Keep' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'android.support.annotation.Keep' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'android.support.annotation.Keep' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'android.support.annotation.Keep' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'android.support.annotation.Keep' (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean calls 'Field.getType' (TaskId:363)
2>PROGUARD : warning : okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
2>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
2>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
2>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
2>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
2>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
2>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
...
2>  Note: there were 7 references to unknown classes. (TaskId:363)
2>        You should check your configuration for typos. (TaskId:363)
2>        (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass) (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: there were 1 classes trying to access generic signatures using reflection. (TaskId:363)
2>        You should consider keeping the signature attributes (TaskId:363)
2>        (using '-keepattributes Signature'). (TaskId:363)
2>        (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes) (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: there were 15 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members. (TaskId:363)
2>        You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes (TaskId:363)
2>        (using '-keep'). (TaskId:363)
2>        (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass) (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: there were 9 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces. (TaskId:363)
2>        You should check if you need to specify additional program jars. (TaskId:363)
2>        (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass) (TaskId:363)
2>  Note: there were 3 accesses to class members by means of introspection. (TaskId:363)
2>        You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members (TaskId:363)
2>        (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers'). (TaskId:363)
2>        (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember) (TaskId:363)
2>PROGUARD : warning : there were 14 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
2>           You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions. (TaskId:363)
2>           If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress (TaskId:363)
2>           the warnings with '-dontwarn' options. (TaskId:363)
2>           (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass) (TaskId:363)
2>  java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first. (TaskId:363)
2>      at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:473) (TaskId:363)
2>      at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:233) (TaskId:363)
2>      at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:98) (TaskId:363)
2>      at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:538) (TaskId:363)
2>  Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 (TaskId:363)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2025,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.
2>Done executing task "Proguard" -- FAILED. (TaskId:363)
2>Done building target "_CompileToDalvikWithDx" in project "MyProjectXXX.Mobile.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:310)
2>
```

I tried increasing the Java heap size to 1G, but that had no effect.

Please let me know if you have any ideas on how to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about that error but I would suggest not using Modern HTTP Client anymore. I use to use it exclusively but now Xamarin allows you to get the same functionality of using native message handlers without the library. I also stopped using it because of uncatchable exceptions on Android coming from the library when a network connection is lost, among other things. These issues have been raised on the GitHub page but none of them are ever actually fixed.

Comment: I think this says it all; `warning : there were 14 unresolved references to classes or interface. You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions. If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.`

Comment: Gerald is onto something. However the actual error is ```2>  java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.``` which implies that you need to fix the warnings above or suppress them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like all you need to do is add a `proguard.cfg` file to your project with build action set to `ProguardConfiguration` to remove any warnings and keep any necessary classes for example:

```
# General Android
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient

# Android Support Library
-keep class android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication
-keep class android.support.v4.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** {
    public *;
}

# Google Play Billing
-keep class com.android.vending.billing.**

# Google Play Services
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.internal.*
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected java.lang.Object[][] getContents();
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks.

Comment: Not a problem proguard can be rather tricky to setup if you've never done it before.

Comment: @Nick I have the same error but I'm unable to solve it using proguard for the first time Help Please!

Comment: If you change logging to verbose and build it should give warnings in the output to the problem package/name you need to add an exception for