# Apk file not working with enabled proguard in xamarin forms Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on xamarin forms and I wanted to reduce the APK size and improve the performance. I tried by enabling the ProGuard to reduce the APK size. But after generating (release) the APK not working. Please, any help would be appreciated.

Unhandleld exception is:

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.companyname.RCBazaar/md514419014412832c50536fe1441e86d52.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsFrameLayout.

```
StackTrace:
```

> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <4f3358c3df0042d0bd6cef1efa29748d>:0 
>     at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00089] in :0 
>     at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x00015] in <9c44aef564514541bb63163656b8198b>:0 
>     at Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity.SetSupportActionBar (Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar) [0x00088] in <4ab3f13aee974899a73f2f846f804630>:0 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x00050] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:164 
>     at RCBazaar.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00018] in D:\manasa\RCBazaar\RCBazaar\RCBazaar\RCBazaar.Android\MainActivity.cs:38 
>    End of managed Java.Lang.RuntimeException stack trace
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsFrameLayout
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)

Comment: Did you read the guidelines for using progaurd?

Comment: yes, I read the documentation and followed using this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/proguard?tabs=vswin

Comment: app is crashing After open the app in device. Apk released using linker sdk assemblies only. By using that linking apk working but when we generate apk with the progaurd not working. Any suggestions for this.

Comment: Did you check what the stacktrace and output have to say when your app crashes?

Comment: I didn't get any information for the app crash

Comment: Can you show me where your app is crashing and what does the exception has to say? By checking the output window

Comment: I have installed apk in device and i can't get the crash report without using any plugins which are used to catch the crash like hockeyapp...

Comment: did you try enabling progaurd and linksdk assemblies in debug?

Comment: Why we want to try in debug can you please tell me

Comment: So that you know what the issue is since you do not have a crash reporter

Comment: I will try that now and let you know

Comment: Sure let me know and in case you face the issue put the stacktrace and exception details

Comment: Yes, I got the exception in MainActivity. Exception is: Java.Lang.RuntimeException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>. In this line of code: Base.base.OnCreate(bundle);

Comment: Put this code in try catch and give me the exception stacktrace please

Comment: I am getting this exception in debug : Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsFrameLayout

Comment: here is the stacktrace :  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <4f3358c3df0042d0bd6cef1efa29748d>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference

Comment: hello @G.hakim, StackTrace text is too long i can't post that here

Comment: Update it in your question please

Comment: Please see the stacktrace why it is coming let me know @G.hakim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first add a file to your project called `proguard.cfg`and set the build action to ProGuardconfiguration

And add the following code to it

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.**
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.**
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.v7.widget.**
-keep class android.support.v4.widget.Space { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.v4.widget.Space
```

Also, add the following to it suggested by Xamarin:

```
-injars  bin/classes
-injars  libs
-outjars bin/classes-processed.jar
-libraryjars /usr/local/java/android-sdk/platforms/android-9/android.jar

-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
 public <init>(android.content.Context);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
 public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
 }

 -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
 }

 -keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
 static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
 }

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
 public static <fields>;
}
```

In case you don't understand [check this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/proguard?tabs=vswin#customizing)

In case of queries revert.

Comment: I am getting error java.exe exited with the code 1 after add progaurd.cfg file to the android project.

Comment: hello @G.hakim, This link through i resolved the error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393942/proguard-java-exe-exited-with-code-1-after-adding-modernhttpclient. Thanks for your support. and i mark this as answer. your suggestion through it is working. Thanks